# Ruby Ebook for building social neworking site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to build a basic Social networking site in Rails. 
Can you please suggest me some ebooks for that or any web resource.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Lovd by Less](http://lovdbyless.com/) is essentially a "social-network starter kit" built on Rails.

Answer (score 0):

RailSpace By Micheal Hartl. It focuses on Rails 1.1 or 1.2 but I'm sure you'll be able to get rolling with that book. 
But if your looking for something specific it would be great if you could list some of your requirements.

.[Practical ROR Social networking sites](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598415)

Answer (score 0):

I can also recommend the Practical ROR Social Networking Sites book that Sid mentioned. I've used it before and it covers pretty much everything you'd want to know about building a "social network" site in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

I can do you one better. http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/creating-a-twitter-clone-in-rails-part-1

This is the screencast for creating a [Twitter](http://toolsoftrade.heroku.com) clone. It deals with following/follower associations. I practically learned how to make my site using the screen cast.

Answer (score 0):

Site points simply rails 2
http://www.sitepoint.com/books/rails2/

This is a great book to start learning rails with. The book focuses on building a site like Reddit/Digg.